# Calling graph API to access oneDrive (office365) via another REST service

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, office365api

We want to upload files via a REST service to our oneDrive. In the REST service we are calling Microsoft Graph API but I am getting the 401 error, which I guess because of authorisation issue, I am wondering what is the best approach here?

The whole process works nicely if on our web-application.

I granted App permission in the Azure Active Directory portal and confirmed the consent at

```
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/adminconsent?client_id=<client-id>
```

Then tried to get token

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant>/oauth2/v2.0/token"
"client_id": credential.clientid
"client_secret", credential.clientsecret
"scope", "https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default"
"grant_type", "client_credentials"
```

I was still getting 401 error.

Then I fixed the permissions, now I get the access_token, now I first checked if a file exists in specific folder in oneDrive, if not then upload the file.

But now I get the following error:

```
{
"statuscode": 403,
"body": "{\r\n  \"error\": {\r\n    \"code\": \"AccessDenied\",\r\n    \"message\": \"Either scp or roles claim need to be present in the token.\",\r\n    \"innerError\": {\r\n      \"date\": \"2020-08-13T10:12:33\",\r\n      \"request-id\": \"338a2758-m7e0-4289-bnna-45pb14c79efa\"\r\n    }\r\n  }\r\n}"
}
```

I used the following API for checking if a file exists:

```
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<siteid>/drive/root:/<filePath>:/children"
```

I am not sure what roles/permission I need to set.